# Has the format to put data in Firebase with HashMap changed?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, hashmap

I am adding data to Firebase in 2 ways. In working with Firebase's FriendlyMessage example. 1st way is the way they have in their example. 2nd is adding userdata in a different node with a HashMap.

I have attached relevant parts of code containing this. But it is not being added to Firebase. Though the 1st way is still working.

[declaring the map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9w0A.jpg)
[putting content in the map. also "chatUsers" node does not yet exist in the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DI3q.jpg)
[adding it to firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W78g2.jpg)

what am I doing wrong here?
or has the method changed? I've been seeing some updates like how to use FirebaseRecyclerAdapter. Is this case somewhat like that?

Comment: Don't post code as image. That's a pain to read and makes us impossible to copy/paste your code.

Comment: @Cid my code is really messed up and badly organized. still i'll upload it

It's a little changed but the nothing is deleted, I just commented out some lines to try the new code

Comment: @Cid before I could upload the code, I solve it. The issue was in the Firebase RULES that were taught in the project.
It allowed read and write only to one particular node, "mesages".
That's why I could not create any more nodes.
Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a blunder.

The issue was in the Firebase RULES that were taught in the project. It allowed read and write only to one particular node, "messages".

```
{
 "rules": {
   "messages": {
     // only authenticated users can read and write the messages node
     ".read": "auth != null",
     ".write": "auth != null",
  }
 }
}
```

As I needed a new node, it just could not be created by these rules.
After updating the rules, things worked.

```
{
 "rules": {
   //"messages": {
     // only authenticated users can read and write the messages node
     ".read": "auth != null",
     ".write": "auth != null",
  //}
 }
}
```

Thank you for your time and effort